# How does a sequence who does not have a limit point behave?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In $R$ every bounded sequence have a limit point. Suppose the sequence and bounded and further say that it does not have a limit point. Would this directly conclude that it goes to infinity?

Can't there be sequences who go to infinity but have limit points?

I mean is the statement below true:
A sequence diverges to infinity if and only if it doesn't have any limit points.

Comment: When you say "goes to infinity" what do you mean?  For example, is the sequence $\{(-1)^nn\}$ a counterexample to what you want?

Comment: Consider the sequence $a_n$ with $a_n=n$ for $n $ odd and $a_n=1/n$ for $n$ even. What is the limit? and there are limits points?

Comment: I'm trying to ask if a sequence diverges to infinity we say that it doesn't have limit points right?

Comment: not having limit points would be equal to no converging subsequences then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_n)\subset\mathbb R$ be a sequence of real numbers. Then exactly one of the following two statements is true.

1. $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|=\infty$
2. There exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ that converges to some (finite) real number (i.e. $(x_n)$ has a limit/accumulation point).

If a sequence does not have any finite limit points (so (2) is not satisfied), then this does not mean that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=+\infty$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=-\infty$. For instance, 
$$
x_n=\begin{cases}n, & n \text{ odd} \\ -n, & n \text{ even}\end{cases}=(1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,...).
$$
Conversely, if we know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=+\infty$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=-\infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|=\infty$, and in this case $(x_n)$ cannot have any finite limit points.

Comment: That's what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assume the sequence $u_n$ has a limit point $a$ and goes to $+\infty$.

take $\epsilon=1$.
$\lim_{n\to +\infty}u_n=+\infty \implies
\exists n_0 \in \mathbb N :$
$\forall n\geq n_0  \;  u_n\geq a+2$

so,  $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ is empty . This is in contradiction with the hypothesis $a$ is a limit point.

we can have a unbounded sequence which has a limit point.

$u_n=n$ if $n$ is even and

$u_n=0$ if $n$ is odd.

A sequence which is not bounded doesn't go automatically to $\infty$.

Comment: "In R every bounded sequence have a limit point. Suppose the sequence and bounded and further say that it does not have a limit point. Would this directly conclude that it goes to infinity?"

Frankly, it is not clear what you are asking.  You say "suppose the sequence is bounded".  Do you know what that [b]means[/b]?  The very definition of "bounded" says that it does **not** "go to infinity"!

Answer (score 0):

One of the corollary of the [Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) is that any real sequence has at least one limit point in $\Bbb R \cup \{ +\infty, -\infty\}$. Hope this answers your question.

Indeed let $u_n$ be a real sequence. If $u_n$ is bounded the theorem states that one of its subsequence converges to a real.

If it is not bounded, that means :

$\forall M \in \Bbb R, \exists n \in \Bbb N, u_n \ge M$ or $\forall M \in \Bbb R, \exists n \in \Bbb N, u_n \le M$

You can therefore construct by induction a subsequence of $u_n$ by selecting an extraction $\phi$ such that $u_{\phi(n+1)} \le \min \{u_k, k \le \phi(n)\}-1$ (or $u_{\phi(n+1)} \ge \max \{u_k, k \le \phi(n)\}+1$), which then diverges either to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$

Thus you can deduce from this that any sequence that does not have a limit point diverges to one (or both) of the infinities.

Comment: No it states that this is the case only if sequence is bounded

Comment: Well if it not bounded this means that there exists a subsequence that diverges ..?

Comment: Check the theorem please, and thats kinda what im asking

Comment: I edited my answer with more detail